# Resetting the Shutter Count on Panasonic Lumix GX80

Tags: panasonic-lumix

I have just purchased a S/H Lumix GX80 from a guy on eBay. In his listing he stated that the shutter count was approximately 2,500 activations. I have now received the camera, but on checking the Shutter Count myself it reveals only 29 activations!
I am suspicious naturally and wonder if the counter has somehow been reset - is that possible? 
I would be grateful for your advice.

Comment: Seems an odd idea to sell it as 2500 and *then* change it to 29, as the buyer was expecting 2500.  Note that either number would be way, way below the rating for the shutter mechanism, so nothing would seem to be gained by making such a change.

Comment: How are you checking the shutter count? Are you really looking at the shutter count or something else, like filename numbering? I've encountered people who think file numbers reflect shutter count. They don't.

Comment: I would rest the camera to factory setttings (there must be an options for this somewhere) and see if this resets the shutter count...

Answer (score 1):

In a way, it might be possible to manipulate the shutter count on a camera, however this takes some technical expertise to do so.

There might be another, easier explanation: Most cameras do not count a photo taken with silent shutter as a shutter count. If the previous owner used that a lot, it might explain the low shutter count.

You can try that by taking down the shutter count, then take one photo with silent (or electronic) shutter and see if the count increases.

Answer (score 1):

All of the things mentioned in [this answer](https://photo.stackexchange.com/a/115185/15871) are certainly some of the possibilities.

Another slim possibility is that the camera has recently been to a Panasonic service facility and the shutter count could have been reset there using proprietary tools most manufacturers have for their cameras. Normally this would only happen if the shutter mechanism was replaced, but there may have been another legitimate reason to do it, or it may have even been an inadvertent action.